# CoreAudio, SandBox & Kernel Errors

Tags: audio, console, sandbox

My console is littered with coreaudio errors. Will trashing the listed components, solve the problem?

[image]

These are all of the logs that mention the word 'region':

[image]

Comment: It does not show the root cause. Something about changing the region? did you do that ?

Comment: Huh, not that I recall...Where would I locate this 'shared region' to attempt to reset it?