# How would I find out if an application installed the wavtap.kext as part of its package?

Tags: audio, midi, kernel-extensions

I'm experiencing [many audiocore errors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143619/coreaudio-sandbox-kernel-errors) and am trying to narrow down the cause.

A Google search has revealed that WavTap could potentially be the cause of these errors.

WavTap is listed in my Audio Midi Setup despite my not having that application installed.

I would like to know if it was installed by some other audio application I have as a tool that this secondary application relies upon to function completely/properly or whether I simply installed WavTap, myself, at some point in the past and missed the .kext when uninstalling. So, how might I go about finding out whether or not another application I have installed has a dependency upon WavTap.kext?

thanks

Comment: in terminal use the mdfind -name WavTap.kext

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that WavTap.kext was installed as a part of the Spotydl package, an application that I had uninstalled nearly immediately and erased most traces of. Removing the WavTap.kext and the Spotydl .plist and .bom appears to have resolved some of the coreaudio errors, though, a reboot will be required to see if the component errors are still present and it seems unlikely that this issue was the cause of those.

If anyone is aware of a simple uninstaller which parses the InstallHistory.plist, please, let me know about it. Thanks

Comment: You know, I haven't been having much luck with AppCleaner and the like actually finding (or bothering to look for?) most of the stray files that are part of an application installation. It's been kind of maddening and seems bizarre to me that there does not seem to be a single script with a GUI that just searches Receipts and parses the results. I'm testing CleanApp right now, but it claims to only work if left running background logging processes constantly to monitor installations and thus gives no guarantee of performing well on applications installed prior to its own installation.

Answer (score 0):

By no means a definitive answer, but I have a pretty comprehensive audio setup here & have no trace of WavTap, which makes it more likely [but not a certainty] that you maybe failed to clean it thoroughly after an install.
I found this code snippet to uninstall it, if you want to give it a try - http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/77263/WavTap-Uninstaller

[code copy for permanent record]

```
#!/bin/bash
# Because WavTap (https://github.com/pje/wavtap) doesn't come with a straightforward way to do it. :\
# Must be run elevated. Mirrors what "make uninstall" does exactly as of June 24, 2014.
osascript -e 'tell application "WavTap"' -e 'quit' -e 'end tell'
rm -rf /Applications/WavTap.app
if [[ "$(kextstat | grep WavTap | grep -v grep)" ]]; then sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/WavTap.kext; fi
rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/WavTap.kext
rm -rf /Library/Receipts/WavTap*
rm -rf /var/db/receipts/*WavTap.*
```

Comment: Thank you. The only one of those items I have is the  WavTap.kext. I'm inclined to agree that it must be leftover from an incomplete uninstallation. Just wish there was a way to search the history of all installed files.

Comment: well, there's Library/Receipts - but it would only tell you if you'd installed it directly, not if some other package had. [edit - I just realised you'd kind of already told me there was no trace in Receipts, sorry ;-)